# nginx subrequest 401 Authorization Required

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to add authorization to access assets. I followed this URL https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/

but I am getting **401 Authorization Required** message on sub request. Following is my **nginx.conf** file -

```
location ~* /static/(.+\.xlsx)$ {
    auth_request  /auth;
    auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
    add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
}

#check authentication

location = /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass    http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/download-csv-format/;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

> Here is what I am getting in browser -

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to do here? The /auth should be going to an external authenticator service that should return a 2xx for allowed or 401/403 for not allowed. In your case, are you just putting a random URL there? That will not return a 200 and your request will fail

Comment: @ManishDash - Thank you for your response, I didn't put a random URL, it is actual URL and returning 200 as well. For security reason, I just used XXX as a placeholder.

Comment: @SachinVairagi Will it be possible to check the access logs for your auth and localhost:8001 server? If the request is forwarded, you should be able to see where your request is landing up

Comment: @DhavalShah - There is no access logs generated for sub-request route

Comment: In that case i suspect that your initial redirection might not be working. Can you try something like (just for testing) "/static/abc.xls" redirecting to "/auth" and see if it is reaching there?

Comment: @SachinVairagi That means your `http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/download-csv-format/` URL returns an HTTP 401 response. You can check it yourself using `curl -v -H 'X-Original-URI: /static/download-format.xlsx' 'http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/download-csv-format/'`

Comment: #1 Are your assets the result of some spa (react, angular, vue) build? #2 Do you need to add a basic authentication or a full oauth2 authorization flow?

Comment: @JRichardsz - Yes, I want to add authentication on SPA (react) assets. I need a basic authentication.

Comment: @IvanShatsky - When I test it with curl, I got following output - {"status":false,"message":"Access denied. No token provided."}